# Create user-related content filter at the same time as user registration with a single form

Tags: php, mysql, object, user-registration

When a user registers I want the user to be created in the database as well as a user filter that references the id in the user table. I am having troubles referencing the id in the form however because the user has not been created yet. Is there any code that would work like: if a user is created successfully use its id here; insert as the filter objects user_id.

register.php

```
     $user = new User();
     $filter = new Filter();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {{

                    $user->create(array(

                        'username' => Input::get('username'),
                        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                        'salt' => $salt,
                        'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'group' => 1,
                        'email' => Input::get('email'),
                        'region' => Input::get('region'),
                        'country' => Input::get('country'),
                        'city_state' => Input::get('city_state')

                    ));

                    $filter->create(array(

                        'user_id' => WHAT DO I PUT HERE, OR IS THIS EVEN THE BEST WAY???
                        'tv'=> 1,
                        'video' => 1,
                        'mobile' => 1
                    ));

                    Session::flash('home', 'Thank you for registering. Enjoy filtwire!');
                    Redirect::to('index.php');

            }} catch(Exception $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what library/class you are using but the User library should/might be returning the id value once it is called. So you will need to place the code between the $user->create and the $filter->create statements.

Comment: I have a class for the user and filter and am trying to create them both at the same time and in the filter's user_id column i want the id that was generated for the user.